# R: How do I group by with mutate in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this tibble.

```
# A tibble: 214 x 3
   launch_year state_name     n
         <int> <fct>      <int>
 1        1965 France         1
 2        1966 France         1
 3        1966 Japan          2
 4        1967 France         2
 5        1967 Italy          1
 6        1967 Japan          1
 7        1968 I-ELDO         1
 8        1969 I-ELDO         1
 9        1969 Japan          1
10        1970 China          1
```

I'd like to add a column for proportions. It would look something like this

```
launches_processed %>%  
  count(launch_year, state_name) %>%
  mutate(prop =  [launches by state_name] / [total launches that year] * 100)
```

I can set `[launches by state_name]` equal to `n`.

How do I get `[total launches that year]`?

Comment: I know you've accepted an answer but is `total launches that year` for all launches by state or for all launches across all states?

Comment: It is for all launches that occurred in that year, by any state.

Comment: and is `launches by state_name` launches by state by year? The proportion calc looks upside down,

Comment: Nice catch. I updated it with the fixed version.

Comment: cool - I added my solution below - it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply group by the `launch_year` to get the sums by that year; add that total as a new column, rename your `n` column given that's the total by state by year and divide by the year's total.

```
library(tidyverse)

launches_processed %>%
  group_by(launch_year) %>% 
  mutate(`total launches that year` = sum(n)) %>%
  rename(`launches by state_name` = n) %>% 
  mutate(prop = `launches by state_name`/ `total launches that year` * 100)
```

Result:

```
   launch_year state_name `launches by state_name` `total launches that year`  prop
         <dbl> <chr>                         <dbl>                      <dbl> <dbl>
 1        1965 France                            1                          1 100  
 2        1966 France                            1                          3  33.3
 3        1966 Japan                             2                          3  66.7
 4        1967 France                            2                          4  50  
 5        1967 Italy                             1                          4  25  
 6        1967 Japan                             1                          4  25  
 7        1968 I-ELDO                            1                          1 100  
 8        1969 I-ELDO                            1                          2  50  
 9        1969 Japan                             1                          2  50  
10        1970 China                             1                          1 100
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (closure) of argument.` after the first mutate()

Comment: Fixed it. Just required changed `n` to `n()`.

Comment: When you do a group_by() and then mutate or summarize with n(), that's saying give me a count of the number of records for each unique value we passed to group_by. Is that right?

Comment: Within each group. Summarise would reduce down whereas mutate keeps all rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this by using a combination of `group_by()` and `ungroup()` in dplyr.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          V1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
          launch_year = c(1965, 1966, 1966, 1967, 1967, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1969, 1970),
          state_name = c("France", "France", "Japan", "France", "Italy", "Japan",
                 "I-ELDO", "I-ELDO", "Japan", "China"),
          V4 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)

df %>%  
  count(launch_year, state_name) %>% 
  group_by(launch_year) %>% 
  mutate(launches_that_year = sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(state_name) %>% 
  mutate(launches_by_state_name = sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(prop = (launches_that_year) / (launches_by_state_name) * 100)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    launch_year state_name     n launches_that_ye~ launches_by_state_~  prop
#>          <dbl> <chr>      <int>             <int>               <int> <dbl>
#>  1        1965 France         1                 1                   3  33.3
#>  2        1966 France         1                 2                   3  66.7
#>  3        1966 Japan          1                 2                   3  66.7
#>  4        1967 France         1                 3                   3 100  
#>  5        1967 Italy          1                 3                   1 300  
#>  6        1967 Japan          1                 3                   3 100  
#>  7        1968 I-ELDO         1                 1                   2  50  
#>  8        1969 I-ELDO         1                 2                   2 100  
#>  9        1969 Japan          1                 2                   3  66.7
#> 10        1970 China          1                 1                   1 100
```

Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This does not give the correct result.  The use of `count` returns the wrong info but there are a couple of other issues as well.